# type casting error when using -std=c++0x

Tags: c++

I recently have to start working with c++ and having a lot of problems. my problem here is I need some functionality which are not supported by the same version of c++. For example the following code read a two column file, tokenize it, and store into dictionary :

```
map<int,int>  ReadTables::lookupTable(string fpath) {
    map<int,int> lookup;    
    ifstream in;
    in.open(fpath.c_str());
    if ( !in.good()) {
        cout << "ERROR: Opening file failed.\n";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    string line;
    const char delimiter[] = " ";
    vector<string> tokens;
    while (!in.eof()){
        getline(in,line);
        tokens = tokenize( line, delimiter );
        lookup[ atoi(tokens[0].c_str())] = atoi(tokens[1].c_str()); 
        //lookup[ stoi(tokens[0])] = stoi(tokens[1]);   
    }
```

This works fine as long as I don't use  `-std=c++0x` flag. When I use this version I got:

```
 *** Break *** segmentation violation


===========================================================
There was a crash.
This is the entire stack trace of all threads:
===========================================================
#0  0x00007fc4782270ee in waitpid () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fc4781b9e8e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fc47cb0a98e in TUnixSystem::StackTrace() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#3  0x00007fc47cb0a223 in TUnixSystem::DispatchSignals(ESignals) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x00007fc478c64050 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x000000000040a83c in ReadTables::lookupTable (this=0x616500, fpath=...) at ../src/ReadTables.cpp:59
#7  0x000000000040ffd8 in main () at ../src/read.cpp:37
===========================================================


The lines below might hint at the cause of the crash.
If they do not help you then please submit a bug report at
http://root.cern.ch/bugs. Please post the ENTIRE stack trace
from above as an attachment in addition to anything else
that might help us fixing this issue.
===========================================================
#5  0x00007fc478c64050 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x000000000040a83c in ReadTables::lookupTable (this=0x616500, fpath=...) at ../src/ReadTables.cpp:59
#7  0x000000000040ffd8 in main () at ../src/read.cpp:37
==========================================================
```

I also realized in `c11` I should use `stoi` which again gives this error :

```
 *** Break *** segmentation violation



===========================================================
There was a crash.
This is the entire stack trace of all threads:
===========================================================
#0  0x00007f26561b50ee in waitpid () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f2656147e8e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f265aa9898e in TUnixSystem::StackTrace() () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#3  0x00007f265aa98223 in TUnixSystem::DispatchSignals(ESignals) () from /usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x00007f2656bf2050 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x000000000040ac44 in std::stoi (__str=..., __idx=0x0, __base=10) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:2567
#7  0x000000000040a8e6 in ReadTables::lookupTable (this=0x616500, fpath=...) at ../src/ReadTables.cpp:62
#8  0x0000000000410178 in main () at ../src/read.cpp:37
===========================================================


The lines below might hint at the cause of the crash.
If they do not help you then please submit a bug report at
http://root.cern.ch/bugs. Please post the ENTIRE stack trace
from above as an attachment in addition to anything else
that might help us fixing this issue.
===========================================================
#5  0x00007f2656bf2050 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x000000000040ac44 in std::stoi (__str=..., __idx=0x0, __base=10) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:2567
#7  0x000000000040a8e6 in ReadTables::lookupTable (this=0x616500, fpath=...) at ../src/ReadTables.cpp:62
#8  0x0000000000410178 in main () at ../src/read.cpp:37
===========================================================
```

What I am missing here? And is there suggestion about which version to use?

Comment: My guess? Your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: On a potentially unrelated note, `while (!in.eof())` [is a broken read loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/46642). Forget the source that taught you that (any minimally decent learning material would get this right; it's not that hard), and pick [a better one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You're already using C++11 with `-std=c++0x`, so use something like `std::stoi` that provides error checking if you plan on continued use of that.

Comment: Just a guess, `tokens[0]` or `tokens[1]` may not be valid indexes. Check the size of the vector returned by `tokenize`.

Comment: Looks like you are passing an invalid string to `atoi` or `stoi` - my guess is that `tokens[0]` or `tokens[1]` is invalid - possibly related to the `while(!in.eof())`, as you'd be processing "empty data" in that case.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes ,Thanks for the tip. That was my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `tokenize` fails to return a vector with at least two elements your code will access past the end of the vector and run into undefined behavior. One such undefined behavior is that your program *appears* to work in C++98 and fails dramatically in C++11 compilation.

Comment: To be clear, your program ISN'T working in C++ 98 - it's failing silently. 'tokens' has the potential to be empty, and you need to check for that before you start accessing it's elements.

Comment: Thanks . The problem was indeed in ` while (!in.eof())`. so changed it to `in>>key>>value` and `lookup[ stoi(key)] = stoi(value)` . Now it works fine. even no need to `tokenize`

Comment: If the values in the file are stored as integers, there is no need to read them in as strings and then convert them.  Just read them in as integers.  `int key, value; {loop} in >> key >> value; lookup[key] = value; {/loop}`.  No need to call `stoi`.

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify your code:

```
std::map<int,int>  ReadTables::lookupTable(const std::string& fpath) 
{
    map<int,int> lookup;    
    std::ifstream fin(fpath.c_str());
    if (!fin.good()) 
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Opening file failed.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // should probably throw an exception here instead of exiting the program
    }

    // load all the integers from the file
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(fin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter<vector<int>>(v));
    assert(v.size() % 2 == 0); // assert that the file loaded key/value pairs
    for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i += 2)
    {
        lookup[v[i]] = v[i + 1];
    }

    fin.close();
    return lookup;
}
```

I'd have to do some digging, but you can probably simplify it even more by tweaking the `std::copy` call to load directly into the `std::map`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. my problem was in ` while (!in.eof())`